# Need pointers to write an extensible reporting engine

Tags: .net, reflection, reporting, extensibility

Frustrated by the current reporting offering's limitations (SSRS, Crystal Reports), and my users being primarily financial/business people familiar with Excel, I am considering to write my own reporting engine using an Excel component like SpreadsheetGear or Aspose.Cells, and integrate it in our WinForms application.

Both libraries offer a spreadsheet viewer WinForms component, so the generated spreadsheet report will be shown to the user in a form, after saving its parameters, and he could then save it.

I've done this on a separate winforms project and it is obviously easy. Just put the parameters controls, in the form, connect to the database, generate the spreadsheet and it is done.

However, doing this for every report would obviously involves a significant duplication of "boilerplate" code and form design and reduces the maintainability and upgradability of the application.

As such, I am considering writing the reports as plugins (DLL), which would only provide the code/logic to generate the report, and would return the final worksheet object to the caller (the "Report Preview" form).

After giving it some thought, I think the responsibilities between the caller and the add-in would be shared as below:

The report DLL/add-in would provide the caller (the master UI) a list of the parameters that the user needs to be pass for this report, along with its name, its possible values (list of a combobox, for example).

It would then be up to the master UI to create those on the form. The control type would be inferred based on the datatype of the parameter (a string would be an TextBox, etc).

The master UI would pass to the report DLL the filled parameters to the report generation method, along with some application specific settings (connection string, application's username).

The Report DLL would then generate the report and return to the master UI the generated worksheet/report object and display it on the preview control.

To achieve this technically, I believe that I need to create an interface for my reports DLLs, and implement methods like

```
List<ReportParameter> GetReportsParameters()
Report GenerateReport()
```

From the master UI, I would access them and call them through Reflection.

Does it sound like a good strategy and does it leave decent room for future extensibility?
I would like to achieve a good balance between modularity while not being restrained in flexibility by my add-in architecture being too static for the future.

Would you have some useful tips to ensure this and share if you achieved similar things in the past?

Thank you.

(I'm developing in C#, .Net 4.0 and WinForms. Database back-end is SQL Server 2005).

Comment: Also, can MS technologies like MEF (Microsoft Extensibility Framework) or MAF (Microsoft Add-in Framerwork) help? Or do they seem to be overkill for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Templater](http://templater.info). It probably already does most of the stuff you want.

There are real world examples on [Github](https://github.com/Templater/Examples).

Disclamer: I'm the author of the library.

Comment: I already visited your site when I was looking for a powerful library and the feeling I had was it wasn't able to cope with large datasets (ie. insert rows from a DataTable or another kind of collection into a destination range) but rather "mail-merge" by search/replacing tags with values. It seems very powerful for that but I'm afraid it is not really what I'm looking for. Please feel free to tell me wrong if I've overlooked something though. Aspose.Cells does something simlilar named "Smart Marker" btw.

Comment: What do you mean by feeling that it wasn't able to cope with large datasets? Templater supports DataTable/IEnumerable/IDataReader/DataSet. It can expand tables/paragraphs/ranges based on items from those collections. Did you took a look at Github examples?